# What is the difference between >> and a new line in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

Let's say I have:

```
task_1 >> task_2
task_3 >> task_4
```

According to my understanding, task_2 will be executed just after task_1 completes, task_3 will be executed just after task_2 completes, and task_4 will be executed just after task_3 completes.

Is that correct? If yes, what is the difference between >> and a new line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

- **Newline**s mean nothing.
- **>>** creates a dependency between tasks.

In your example, *task_1* and *task_3* can start executing at the exact same time, or *task_3* could even start first because there's no explicit restriction between them. The only 2 restrictions you're imposing are that *task_2* can only start after *task_1* finishes and *task_4* can only start after *task_3* finishes.

**Long answer:**
A useful tip to understand the difference here is the fact that there are two main processes running, one based on Python's way of running things (sequential execution) and another based on a dataflow-programming style (DAG's with dependencies).

An Airflow DAG is built or updated each time the scheduler reads a python script and is checked for tasks' execution afterward.

During the build process, the scheduler runs each Python line as a regular Python interpreter would, meaning lines (including newlines) are executed sequentially.

During the task execution process, the scheduler checks the latest DAG it just built and looks at the database to fetch the status of each task to be able to schedule new tasks for execution if their dependencies (defined via >>) have been met.

Answer (score 0):

>> creates dependencies between the tasks, so airflow knows which tasks to reset if you clear part of the pipeline, for instance.

That a task is computed after another one does not imply dependency.

Answer (score 0):

[DAG Writing Best Practices in Apache Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dag-best-practices/)

> depends_on_past and wait_for_downstream can be used for added safety
>   depends_on_past and wait_for_downstream are set at the DAG level, but
>   filters down to tasks. If depends_on_past is set to true, the
>   previously scheduled task instance needs to have succeeded before the
>   next task instance will be scheduled (assuming all dependencies are
>   met). Additionally, if wait_for_downstream is set to true, a task will
>   wait for all tasks downstream of the previously scheduled task to
>   finish before being scheduled.
>
> Using these effectively can help ensure data integrity when scheduling
>   a backfill where data is aggregated by some time interval.

```
task_2.set_downstream(task_1)    
task_4.set_downstream(task_3)
```

or this

```
task_1 >> task_2
task_3 >> task_4
```